# React Native ios - change TextInput padding not work

Tags: react-native

I want to change padding of `TextInput` when `onFocus()`, but I failed. Does anyone know why?

Below is my code.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        textInputStyle: {
            paddingLeft: 0,
        }
    };
};

setPadding = () => {
this.setState({
    textInputStyle: {
        paddingLeft: 40,
        }
    })
};

render() {
    return (
               <TextInput
                   style={this.state.textInputStyle}
                   onFocus={this.setPadding}
                />
    );
};
```

[This is the screenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BScqO.png)